# Error with psmouse serio1: Failed to deactivate/enable on Dell XPS 15 7590

Tags: mouse, touchpad, dell

I am having these "psmouse" errors

```
$ dmesg | grep -i psmouse

[   13.463294] psmouse serio1: Failed to deactivate mouse on isa0060/serio1: -5
[   13.943488] psmouse serio1: Failed to enable mouse on isa0060/serio1
[   18.454190] psmouse serio1: Failed to enable mouse on isa0060/serio1
```

I do not know how to disable/blacklist this psmouse and how to fix this error because when I power off my laptop this error gets a lot of time to vanish (or the error itself or a blinking dash).

I am on a Dell XPS 15 7590 runnnig Ubuntu 20.04 on 5.4 kernel.

Answer (score 0):

We have many ways to disable/blacklist `psmouse`.

One is to edit the `/etc/default/grub` file:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

You can type:

```
module_blacklist=psmouse
```

or

```
modprobe.blacklist=psmouse
```

Save the modifications, run the command `update-grub` with root privileges as:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Finally reboot.